# find package with multiple names pacman

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, pkgbuild

Some packages like `gcc-libs` are apparently other packages, under a different name. turns out `gcc-libs` is just `gcc`: [`PKGBUILD`](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/blob/packages/gcc/trunk/PKGBUILD)

if I want to install that package, I know I can run `pacman -S gcc-libs`, but how can I find the original package, as in, the package which has a `PKGBUILD` named after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are called split packages (see *PACKAGE SPLITTING* section of [`PKGBUILD`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/PKGBUILD.5) manual). I guess what you want is the `pkgbase` name and you can get that with  [`pacinfo`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/pacutils/pacinfo.1.en) from [`pacutils`](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/pacutils/) e.g.

```
pacinfo lib32-gcc-libs
```

prints

```
Name:           lib32-gcc-libs
Base:           gcc
Repository:     core
.................................
```

so the `Base:` key means `pkgbase` name, in this case `gcc`